# Will Liquibase updateSQL command line throw error if the changeset was already applied ?

Tags: database-schema, liquibase

The updateSQL liquibase command does not seem to throw an error when running updateSQL command line as it generates  the relevant SQL statements for the changeset along with an entry to be created in DATABASECHANGELOG table.

My requirement is that I can only generate the SQL and hand it over to my DBA. But will liquibase throw error even if one of the changeSets in the xml fails to get created prior to generating the SQL for the changeset ?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UpdateSQL will not fail if a changeSet is already ran. The purpose of Liquibase is to track which changeSets have been applied and only "execute" changeSets that have not been ran while skipping ones that have.

If you run in regular update mode, Liquibase will directly execute each changeSet in turn. If you run in updateSql mode, Liquibase will not actually execute the SQL but instead output what it would have ran.

Liquibase will not throw any errors in updateSQL. However, if the state of the database you are going to execute the SQL file against is different than the database you run updateSQL against, the resulting SQL may not be valid. There is no re-checking of whether a changeSet has executed in the SQL output, it is just a simple "run these commands" script.